# Disable button on submit and enable native form validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Browsers have a nice tooltip that appears when a field with the `required` attribute has not been filled in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" required>
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value="Submitted...";this.form.submit()">
</form>
```

[image: ola amigo]

The problem is I have this submit button disabled when the user submits the form so it wouldn't be submitted multiple times, and after submitting (even if the required field is empty) the form still submits. Is there a fix so that the browser will check on the required fields before submitting?

Comment: Check [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) out it might help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the required fields are actually filled in before you disable the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" required>
<input type="submit" onclick="if (document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value != null) {
                                this.disabled=true;
                                this.value='Submitted...';
                                this.form.submit();
                              }">
</form>
```

Or you could use `document.querySelectorAll()` for multiple required ones:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name" required>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Email address" required>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Phone number">
<input type="submit" onclick="for (x in document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][required]')) {
                                if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text][required]').value != null) {
                                  this.disabled=true;
                                  this.value='Submitted...';
                                  this.form.submit();
                                }
                              }">
</form>
```

Comment: this would be a headache if i had 10 input fields.