# HTML/JavaScript: Execute form submit checks on button-press; is it possible in an elegant way?

Tags: javascript, validation, html-input, submit-button

I wrote an input form that has `input` elements with the `required` attribute set.

So when pressing an `<input type="submit" />` button, empty fields (and other violations) are complained about.

However when I use an  `<input type="button" onClick="something()" />` button, the function is called even if the required input is empty.

Example input field:

`<input id="customer-name" type="text" name="i.user.name" size="25" maxlength="40" placeholder="Name" pattern="^[^ ]..+$" required="required" />`

Is there a way to execute what a submit button would do without adding a submit button?
I mean not repeating the logic in JavaScript as indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11380269/6607497.

Basically while testing I wrote the code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) in a local file, loaded in a browser.
So an actual submit button would be tricky at least (IMHO).

Comment: Why are you not just using a submit button and use form submission event... Why reinvent the wheel to use onclick? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity

Comment: The answer suggested (and question) uses jQuery; I do not.

Comment: The same concepts apply, though. The jQuery is easily translated to vanilla JS and you would still checkValidity()/reportValidity().

Comment: @U.Windl most of those answers have zero jQuery in them.I am still curious on why you can not use a submit button and just cancel the submit action...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77416356/6607497